# How to run wall command as another user in Linux (RHEL8)

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo

How do I send a wall message as root (or any other user) and it not identify the original user?

Looking at the below I would have expected wall to display message **from root** but it still shows **admin1**, what am I missing?

I have tried various sudo -i, -s, using -c to send command, tmux, runuser but always the same result. Is it a global setting in sudoers or something else?

For context this was a question on a test I couldn't figure out and not been given an answer!

```
[admin1@RHELPOC ~]$ sudo su -
[root@RHELPOC ~]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[root@RHELPOC ~]# wall "whoisthis"

Broadcast message from admin1@RHELPOC (pts/0) (Fri Jan  8 13:58:40 2021):
whoisthis
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `wall` uses `getlogin()` to find the name of the user.

```
if (!(whom = getlogin()) || !*whom)
            whom = (pw = getpwuid(getuid())) ? pw->pw_name : "???";
        if (!whom) {
            whom = "someone";
            warn(_("cannot get passwd uid"));
        }
```

And then:

```
snprintf(lbuf, line_max,
                _("Broadcast message from %s@%s (%s) (%s):"),
                whom, hostname, where, date);
```

From the `getlogin` man page:

> getlogin() returns a pointer to a string containing the name of the
> user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process, or a NULL
> pointer if this information cannot be determined.
>
> ...
>
> These functions let your program identify positively the user who is
> running (cuserid()) or the user who logged in this session
> (getlogin()). (These can differ when set-user-ID programs are
> involved.)

Comment: So how would you send a wall message as root, if you only have admin credentials capable of sudo and can't login directly as root? Is it possible with a bash script and set-user-id?